# Overlap of numbers on colorbar when use subplot and heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, colorbar

[Overlapped two heatmaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxXiv.png)
[Another two with same color level of heatmaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Gy4d.png)

The level of all four heatmaps are fixed and the same. But since the data is different, the max and min are different. Then it appears the color index overlap. I tried to change the level of heatmap but doesn't work.

Here is code:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
fig.set_size_inches(16.5, 5.5)

X1 = np.linspace(1950, 2035, 86)
Y1 = np.linspace(20, 95, 76)
X1,Y1 = np.meshgrid(X1,  Y1)
Z1 = F_proj_SOA17.iloc[20:-5,4:]
norm = mcolors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=(Z1.to_numpy()).min(), vmax = (Z1.to_numpy()).max(), vcenter=0)
level = np.arange(-0.07, 0.07, 0.003)
DV = ax1.contourf(X1,Y1,Z1,level,cmap=plt.cm.RdBu_r, extend='both', norm=norm)
ax1.set_title('MIR 1951-2035 for Female (SOA17)')
ax1.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(1960, 2036, 20))
ax1.axvline(x=2016, c = 'black', linestyle = ':')
fig.colorbar(DV, ax=ax1)

X2 = np.linspace(1950, 2036, 87)
Y2 = np.linspace(20, 95, 76)
X2,Y2 = np.meshgrid(X2,  Y2)
Z2 = F_proj_DV18.iloc[20:-5,4:]
norm = mcolors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=(Z2.to_numpy()).min(), vmax = (Z2.to_numpy()).max(), vcenter=0)
level = np.arange(-0.07, 0.07, 0.003)
MP = ax2.contourf(X2,Y2,Z2,level,cmap=plt.cm.RdBu_r, extend='both', norm=norm)
ax2.set_title('MIR 1951-2036 for Female (SOA17HMD18)')
ax2.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(1960, 2036, 20))
ax2.axvline(x=2016, c = 'black', linestyle = ':')
ax2.axvline(x=2017, c = 'black', linestyle = ':')
fig.colorbar(MP, ax=ax2)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you add full code to create a minimal reproducible example? Apart from that, when creating the heatmaps, you could set `vmin=` and `vmax=` to the same value for each of the subplots.

Comment: @JohanC I have add the full code. and I already used the vmin and vmax. But I don't know why there is overlap of index.

Comment: You could set `vmin=min(Z1.min(), Z2.min())` for both plots to have them equal. As the values are almost symmetrical to zero, you could also replace the TwoSlopeNorm with a simple norm, setting both vmin and vmax to the same absolute maximum with different signs. A simple approach could use `norm=plt.Normalize(-0.07,0.07)`, which also would make it easier to compare different plots.

Comment: @JohanC I tried plt.Normalize(-0.07,0.07) and it works well! there is no overlap again although the color changed a little bit lighter. Thanks so much for your help!